# Using wxWidgets with CMAKE and visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, compiler-errors, wxwidgets

Every time I try to build my project with CMAKE having the wxWidgets as library I get a lot of linker errors LNK I even get two errors for just compiling my main.cpp that only includes this :

```
#include "wx/wx.h"
int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

I just downloaded the source code of wxwidgets, put it in a lib folder and linked it with cmake
This is my CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# set the project name
project(wxtest VERSION 1.0)

add_subdirectory(libs/wxWidgets)
add_executable(wx_test WIN32 src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(wx_test wx::net wx::core wx::base)
```

**Here are the errors:
Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals

Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol WinMain referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)**

Is there anything wrong with linking the wxWidgets lib to my project ?

Comment: What specific errors are you seeing? Does CMake know where to find the header files and library files?

Comment: We cannot help you without looking into the error message(s).

Comment: I added the errors messages into the question

Answer (score 2):

wxWidgets programs are compiled as GUI Win32 applications and so use `WinMain()` entry point by default, which you don't define.

The usual way to define it is by using `wxIMPLEMENT_APP()` macro, but you may also do it manually if you really need to -- but you must define it, one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a few days figuring this out and read a lot of posts and answers which were out of date or only paritial answers. This is the process that worked for me.

WxWidgets for windows prefers being setting up for use by a standard .sln solution. Since VS Solutions are NOT cross platform, that's not the best build system for a cross platform GUI like wxWidgets.
A few versions back, Microsoft added CMake support to VS to support cross platform development, but it looks like the WxWidget build system hasn't caught up yet.

The linux install and build of wxWidgets took a few hours. It took several days to get Visual Studio 2020 working, and these are my notes on how to do it again. Hope you find it helpful.

I had no luck using any of the precompiled options because important items like wxWidgetsConfig.cmake and its subcomponents are ommitted. Also, there's an installer, header file and precompiled libraries in separate zip files and how to assemble them is left as an exercise for the reader.

Only building from source worked and installed correctly and that required many undocumented steps. I'm assuming these steps are common knowledge for those who's day to day jobs are building and installing with CMake,
but for others these steps are NOT obvious. For example there is no sudo for windows.

Download the .zip or .7z file with all the sources per instructions.
Expand them anywhere. This will be referred to as <SourceDir>.

Open an x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022 AS ADMIN!! You will not be able to install without admin priveleges. There's a lot of documentation to do this, and it's out of date for 2022.
Click start (windows menu, lower left)
Type x64
Look for "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022" and select "run as admin" - this will open a command prompt that will work.

cd to the newly created folder, should be wxWidgets-3.x.y.z.
make a temp folder, mine was buildWin. I refer to this as <BuildDir>.

cd <BuildDir>

Launch CMakeGui.exe FROM THE x64 COMMAND LINE! I tried this from the Start menu and it failed. This worked, so I stuck with it. I suspect that if you launch CMake from the start menu as admin it will work just as well.
If you do this without running as admin, the installer will not be allowed to create directories under "Program Files" due to insufficient priveleges.

Set CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX to "Program Files" or "Program Files (x86)" as appropriate.

Chose nmake as the build system

Choose <SourceDir> for "Where is the source"

Choose <BuildDir> for "where to put the binaries."

Click configure once - it will generate a few errors

Do the following as a loop. Each iteration will produce and install a configuration.

Choose CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE - it looks like a text field, but it's actually a menu. It took about a day to realize it can be clicked on.

Choose other settings such as wxBUILD_shared or wxBUILD_MONOLITHIIC. I recommend monolithic. Size is not so important these days and it will save you worlds of pain guessing which libraries you need later.

Click configure again - this will clear any red error colors. You can skip this step on 2nd+ iterations

Click generate

When generate completes

execute "nmake" from the command line

When nmake completes

execute "cmake --install ." from the command line. The "." seems wrong as it usually means "install in this directory" but it will install in the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX chosen in CMakeGui.exe

Check that the appropriate files were placed in the correct "Program Files" folder you chose in CMakeGui.

Repeat for each configuration.

You should now have everything built and in the correct place. The default location is C:\wxWidgets, I suggest sticking with that.

I added the following system environment variables

wxWidgets_DIR = c:\wxWidgets\

wxWidgets_LIB_DIR = c:\wxWidgets\lib

These environment variables are needed by CMake's find_package tool so it can find where everything is.

If you created a shared library, you need to make it discoverable on your system. Do the following to do that.

Using the settings tool, add an entry to the system environment variable Path. "C:[your Program Files][your wxWidgets]\lib[your config vc_x64_dll]" This will allow Windows to fild your dll.
NOTE, as of this writing, I have not gotten an exe file using a dll to work yet, but I can build from libraries.

At this stage your windows system should be able to build and run wxWidget based exe files hard linked to libs.

Fragments of the CMakeLists.txt file in order - I did not have time make a standalone version.

```
find_package(wxWidgets)
include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})

if ("${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" STREQUAL "Release")
    set(WX_INCLUDE_CONFIG_PATH "${wxWidgets_DIR}/vc_x64_lib/mswu/")
    set(WX_LIB_NAMES "comctl32.lib Rpcrt4.lib wxmsw32u.lib wxpng.lib wxregexu.lib wxzlib.lib")
else()
    set(WX_INCLUDE_CONFIG_PATH "${wxWidgets_DIR}/vc_x64_lib/mswud/")
    set(WX_LIB_NAMES "comctl32.lib Rpcrt4.lib wxmsw32ud.lib wxpngd.lib wxregexud.lib wxzlibd.lib")
endif()
```

wxWidgets uses "d" to distinguish a debug library instead of putting it in a debug folder, so we had to mangle the lib names. We also have to add any required windows library that the solution normally adds for us (comctl32.lib Rpcrt4.lib etc.)

```
include_directories(
  <yours>
  "${wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS}"
)

link_directories (
    <yours>
    ${wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR}/lib/vc_x64_lib/
)

add_executable (<YourProjectName>
    WIN32
    <yours>
)

target_link_libraries(<YourProjectName> 
    ${WX_LIB_NAMES}
    <yours>
)
```

You may need to add wxWidgets compile flags to

```
target_compile_features(<YourProjectName> PRIVATE <yours> ${wxWidgets_CXX_FLAGS})
```

I didn't need to for my case.

At this point I can open the project's CMakeLists.txt file from VS 2022, select a configuration, build, run and debug like a regular solution using VS 2022 - with no solution file.

To state what should be obvious, you can place the windows specific CMake steps inside a CMake if statement, and other builds in other branches of the if, so you can use the same CMakeLists.txt file on all platforms.

Comment: I've been working with computers since 1976 on an IBM 360 with a paper printer console and my first big project was on punch cards - I've been around:)

Installation and setup is the unrecognized time suck of compiled languages and one of the primary reasons developers are migrating to interpreted languages.

Installation testing must always be performed by a naive user who knows nothing. This makes installation testing ridiculously expensive - because you can't reuse testers.

I just spent two weeks setting up the env for a two week job and that's too expensive.